# How to translate tens of images from a directory as a batch with gdal_translate?

Tags: gdal-translate, batch

For example i have a dataset of images in *.cub format like

```
$path: /work/120614/mg_1164/
f01.img.cub_E.cub
f02.img.cub_E.cub
'
'
f0n.img.cub_E.cub
```

for converting a single image I use `gdal_translate f01.img.cub_E.cub fo1.tif`
for whole the datasets.HOW? batch file?

Answer (score 12):

I suggest a batch file using OSGEO4W shell or the latest GDAL binaries from gisinternals.

Using Windows:

```
for %%N in (/work/120614/mg_1164/*.cub) DO gdal_translate %%N /work/temp/%%~nN.tif
```

Note: Use `%%N` in a batch file and `%N` when typing manually on the command line.

Comment: "%%N" what exactly it is..

Comment: It may look funny but i m very new to this stuff help me

Comment: %%N is the DOS variable that runs through all files in the directory matching .cub extension. Just type it the same way. %%~nN is the file name without extension.

Comment: but when i execute this in OSGEO4W shell reflecting an errot and it is "%%N was unexpected at this time". What doese this mean?

Comment: You have to write the line in a text file named something like test.bat. Then call that inside the OSGEO4W shell.

Comment: Use `%%N` in a batch file and `%N` on the command line.

Answer (score 9):

If using a linux OS, you can use a for loop in your shell:

```
for f in *.cub; do
     gdal_translate "$f" "${f%.*}.tif"
done
```

For more information on what this is doing,  see the accepted answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/737471

Comment: This is not working for directories that contain more than a single input file.

Comment: Sorry for the noise, the issue was caused by spaces in the file name: `myraster (copy).jpg`

Comment: @eclipsed_by_the_moon use double quotes, see edited answer.