# gdal_translate COMPRESS=JPEG SyntaxError: invalid syntax error

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate, compression

Following is the code I'm using to compress set of .tif images to .jpg. My objective is to iterate through each .tif image and create a new set of compressed jpg images.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import os
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    #print(filename.split("."))
    if(filename.split(".")[1] == "tif"):
        print(filename.split(".")[0])
        gdal_translate \
          -co COMPRESS=JPEG \
          -co TILED=YES \
          filename.split(".")[0].tif  filename.split(".")[0].jpg
```

Though I don't see an error in this code. I followed the technique mentioned in [this blog post](https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html)., I'm getting the following error when I try to execute the above code. The error message is:

```
  File "test.py", line 8
    -co COMPRESS=JPEG \
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: `gdal_translate` is a commandline executable, not a python module.  Either run it from a command prompt/shell terminal or use the `gdal.VectorTranslate` python method.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're attempting to save as JPEG files.  In which case GDAL would use the JPEG raster driver.  The JPEG raster driver does not have a `COMPRESS=` creation option.  See the driver's documentation at https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/jpeg.html#raster-jpeg and scroll down to see the list of creation options.

In fact, setting a compression option to `JPEG` for a JPEG file wouldn't make sense, anyhow, as JPEGs are always JPEG compressed.  It's just a matter of how much they are compressed (versus the quality retained - JPEG compression is lossy).  You could use the `QUALITY=` creation option for JPEGs to control the quality versus compression.

Alternatively, you could save the files as TIFF files (using the GDAL GTIFF driver), and then you could use the `COMPRESS=JPEG` creation option which would use JPEG compression within a TIFF file.  But the output files would be TIFFs, not JPEGs.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Son of a Beach ;) . I'll look more into this. My objective was to compress .tif to jpg for rendering purposes and maintain native .tif separately for download purposes. I found a technique to do so. thanks for your comment.

Comment: Using JPEG for rendering is not a good idea. The whole JPEG image must be decompressed each time even if you need just a small part from the image. Use JPEG compressed and tiled TIFF instead `-of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=jpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this short shell script does what I want. The script is inspired from the answer that appeared in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101800/how-to-translate-tens-of-images-from-a-directory-as-a-batch-with-gdal-translate) post.

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *.tif; do
     #gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co TILED=YES "$f" "${f%.*}.jpg"
     gdal_translate  "$f" "jpg/${f%.*}.jpg"
done
```

Comment: I wonder what you get as a result. Could you add gdalinfo from a resulting file?